# Requesting Sales Order Data from Netsuite Web Service (Suitetalk)

Tags: rest, netsuite, suitetalk

I want to extract Sales Orders from my netsuite instance. To test this I use postman. When using the Netsuite REST API Tutorial Environment with the url:

```
{{proto}}://{{host}}/rest/platform/{{version}}/record/salesorder
```

(postman fills the variables with environment values)

 I should get a JSON object that contains a list of all sales orders.

But I get this error :

```
{
    "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
    "title": "Invalid search query Record 'transaction' was not found. Reason: INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS - Missing permissions for this record.",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorCode": "INVALID_PARAMETER"
}
```

I have tried giving the role that i use for my web service user a lot of permissions, but i havent found the right one yet.
What permissions are needed, to make this get-request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for your request to work, you will need at least these two permissions:

*Manage Roles > Edit > Permissions > Transactions:*

- **Find Transaction**
- Sales Order

Plus of course you need Integration permissions:

*Manage Roles > Edit > Permissions > Setup:*

- Log in using Access Tokens
- REST Web Services

*Manage Roles > Edit > Permissions > Reports:*

- SuiteAnalytics Workbook

Comment: Is there any reference document for this?

Comment: Some of it is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1544787084.html but I agree that adding the permission "Find Transaction" was not obvious!